# Assigning function __dict__ items to functool.partial

Tags: python, functools

#### Problem

Given the following code (an arbitrary decorator which just assigns data to some callable)

```py
from typing import Callable

def decorator() -> Callable:
    def wrapper(f: Callable) -> Callable:
        f.foo = "bar"
        return f

    return wrapper


@decorator()
def func(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b
```

If I attempt the following, I get the expected behaviour.

```py
>>> func.foo
"bar"

>>> func(1,2)
3
```

If however I want to use `functools.partial`, the `f.foo = "bar"` relationship is "*broken*"

```py
>>> from functools import partial
>>> p = partial(func, a=1)
>>> p(b=2)
3

# As expected, p.foo raises an attribute error
>>> p.foo
AttributeError: 'partial' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

I realise I can access this via `p.func.foo`. But I was curious if there was a better way to re-establish the relationship when using partial.

#### Attempted solution

The following workaround seems to "*work*", but I was curious if there is a better approach. Overriding `__new__` is odd, so I opted to override `__init__`

```py
class new_partial(partial):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for k, v in self.func.__dict__.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

Given the above, the following now works

```py
>>> p = new_partial(func, a=1)
>>> p(b=2)
3

>>> p.foo
"bar"
```

Comment: There isn't another workaround for this. Partial wraps the function and returns a new object, on which you do not have control over, so you can't expect the `.foo` attribute on that object too. You can nonetheless access `p.func.foo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan ahead, you can decorate the partial'd version of the function separately:

```
def func(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

p = decorator()(partial(func, 1))
func = decorator()(func)
```

You could also just decorate the partial anyway, if you don't mind the existence of a separate `p.foo` and `func.foo`.

For decorators that create a new function (rather than setting attributes on the original), you can use `functools.wraps` so that the function will remember its original in the `__wrapped__` attribute, and partial and redecorate that:

```
from functools import partial, wraps

def get_name(func):
    try:
        return func.__name__
    except AttributeError: # handle a partial
        return 'a partial application of ' + get_name(func.func)

def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"this is a decorated version of {get_name(func)}")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@decorator
def decorated_sum(x, y):
    return x + y

increment = decorator(partial(decorated_sum.__wrapped__, 1))
```

You could potentially even make a helper function to look for a `__wrapped__` attribute, but you'd need to build your own way to figure out which decorators to apply.